# Dojo Version of jQuery "on" Click

Tags: dojo

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo" data-something="earth">one</li>
    <li class="foo" data-something="wind">two</li>
    <li class="foo" data-something="fire">three</li>
</ul>
```

To get the value of `data-*` attributes, in jQuery i would write:

```
$(document).on('click', '.foo', function(e){
   // get the attribute of the specific .foo that was clicked
   // clicking "two" assigns the value "wind" to bar
   var bar = $(this).data('something');
});
```

In Dojo, i tried:

```
on(query('.foo'), 'click', function(e){
   // get the attribute of the specific .foo that was clicked
   var bar = dojo.attr(this, 'data-something');
});
```

But i'm finding that the `this` context is "not working" as expected/wanted and i'm getting `n` amount of `bar` instead of 1. I tried:

```
query('.foo').forEach(function(e) {
    on(e, 'click', function(evt) {
        var bar = dojo.attr(this, 'data-something');
    });
});
```

But am not getting a consistent result....Essentially i want to access `data-*` attributes from the particular `.foo` click, not all, and would be grateful for a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong because your first try works for me, perhaps there's something buggy in a piece of code you're not sharing? Here's a working example:

```js
require([
    'dojo/on',
    'dojo/query',
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function(
    on,
    query
) {

    on(query('.foo'), 'click', function (e) {
       var bar = dojo.attr(this, 'data-something');
       alert(bar);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="foo" data-something="earth">one</li>
            <li class="foo" data-something="wind">two</li>
            <li class="foo" data-something="fire">three</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, that's good and bad news i suppose, but it wouldn't surprise me in the slightest if there was something buggy in the actual code! Thanks, at least i was on the right track...